# End of week day for a date in Tableau

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, tableau-api

I have date field in this format

```
dateID
>>20150617
```

And I want to get

```
end_of_week_day
>>2015-06-20
```

So for all the dates in a week, I want to get same `end_of_week_day`.

Is there any function in Tableau to do this? I am using Amazon Redshift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is to convert that to a date. Use DATEPARSE to that. Or perhaps just convert the data type of the field and Tableau may understand.

Now for the actual calculation. You want to get the Saturday of that week. DATEPART, using 'weekday', will return a number, 1 for Sunday till 7 for Saturday. So:

```
DATEADD('day',7-DATEPART('weekday',dateID),dateID)
```

should do the trick

Comment: Yes above solution works. For date parsing I need to use


>> convert(datetime,dateID))

Thanks